# Am trying to parse String intto Double, is it possible?

Tags: java, parsing, methods

Please is this being smart or stupid..i tried to return a String in a method of type double..

```
 public double withdrawCash()
 {
    if (amounts == 20)
    {
        totalWithdrawal = BALANCE - 20;
        return totalWithdrawal;
    }else if (amounts == 40){
        totalWithdrawal = BALANCE - 40;
        return totalWithdrawal;
    }else if (amounts == 60){
        totalWithdrawal = BALANCE - 60;
        return totalWithdrawal;
    }else if (amounts == 100){
        totalWithdrawal = BALANCE - 100;
        return totalWithdrawal;
    }else if (amounts == 200){
        totalWithdrawal = BALANCE - 200;
        return totalWithdrawal;
    }
    else{ //this where i tried to be smart or stupid...just learning..help!!!
        String complainWithdrawal = "Please, you need to select appropriate amount";
        double showWithdrawal = Double.parseDouble(complainWithdrawal);
        return showWithdrawal;
    } 
}
```

Kindly advice me on the ideal solution

Comment: You can't return a string from a method that states it returns a double. That would make programming a nightmare. You can throw an exception. That said where does `amounts` come from?

Comment: You can't return a `String` as a `double`. Looks to me like you need to throw an exception in case `amounts` isn't one of your expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String bla = "12.25";

    double showWithdrawal = 0;

    try {
        showWithdrawal = Double.parseDouble(bla);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    System.out.println(showWithdrawal);
```

You can do like that

Answer (score 1):

```
double showWithdrawal = Double.parseDouble(complainWithdrawal);
```

This line will throw an error. You cannot return a String as a double. Instead, you can replace it with:

```
throw new InputMismatchException("Please, you need to select appropriate amount.");
```

And catch it outside like this:

```
try {
    withdrawCash();
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Error withdrawing cash: " + e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I also suggest that for money you don't use double.  Take a look at BigDecimal as well.  There are a lot of issues you will run into down the road using double for monetary values.